# filter out json with json.loads(r.text)

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask, flask-restful

I am trying to fetch rest api from XYZ provider inside python/flask webApp I used this as example/guide https://help.parsehub.com/hc/en-us/articles/217751808-API-Tutorial-How-to-get-run-data-using-Python-Flask
I dont have api key but auth token so this is code I am using and returns alldata

```
`from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
  headers = {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Authorization": "Bearer MYKEY"
  }
  r = requests.get(
      'https://st1.example.com/restapi/domains/', headers=headers)
  return  json.loads(r.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

`

and this return all json data like this
[json image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bdan.png)

Id  like to filter is to display only one part "domain" and "destination" but when adding code like this

```
  r = requests.get(
      'https://st1.example.com/restapi/domains/', headers=headers)
  return  json.loads(r.text)['destination']
```

I keep getting "Key error "destination" " or whatever I put in there

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS36W.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your json returns data which is an array that contains `destination`. Assuming you want the first destination, try

```
  return  json.loads(r.text)['data'][0]['destination']
```

Or it coulde be written as:

```
results = json.loads(r.text)
return results['data'][0]['destination']
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `'destination'` is stored under `'data'` in the JSON response. Also, you should just call `r.json()` instead of `json.loads(r.text)`. You should also `jsnoify` your response.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer MYKEY"
    }
    r = requests.get(
        'https://st1.example.com/restapi/domains/', headers=headers
    )
    destination = r.json()['data'][0]['destination']
    return  jsonify(destination), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```